# Excel cell data to VB.NET output

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am very novice at Visual Basic but I needed this for my thesis in engineering. How do you link an Excel file to Visual Basic, then displaying a cell value in textbox, listview, and others? I have a separate Excel file containing data, and a program.

Comment: I imagine that would be possible. Have you done any research on this using a search engine?

Comment: http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_open_file.htm check here for information on how to do this

Comment: I've done a lot of searches but haven't found one.

Comment: Would try this. Thanks!

Comment: @Jaxi the link is about editing a cell in an excel file. Do you have links on how to link an excel to VB.net, then display a cell value to a textbox or listviews?

Comment: @RavLlave the link i provided shows how to link an excel sheet to a VB.net form, as well as getting the data.

Comment: What tools are you using to code? Use the `interop` assemblies to access the MS Office (Excel) API - you can open and manipulate an Excel file easily this way. And yes, manipulate includes reading data which you can then use in your VB.Net forms.